# SPLUNK MINT throwing ssl error in Android studio

Tags: android, android-support-library, splunk, splunk-sdk

when I run my program its throwing "ssl error" and  "remote host terminated the handshake".

Currently I am using the below library in build.gradle. I have tried upgrading to 5.2.5 but in its website it shows they have stopped the service. Even tried other methods but nothing worked. How can I solve this?

repositories

```
{
url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
}
```

dependency

```
{
implementation 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.4.0'
}
```

1)Tried adding

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
```

2. removed .gradle and .idea and ran the code
3. changed the sdk
4. accept non-trusted certificates automatically
5. added

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=x
systemProp.https.proxyPort=y
systemProp.https.proxyHost=x
systemProp.http.proxyPort=y
```

but this throws error as x is not recognised